# How can I edit lines in one single Excel cell using C#

Tags: c#, excel

I'm using a C# WPF application to create an Excel File.
At some point, I have cells that contains differents lines (using \n)

I try to edit the font color / bold(or not) of these lines using XLWorkbook where we can change this kind of parameters, but, I only found ways to affect the whole cell, which I'm not interested in.

Using IXLCell and RichText, that I'm not sure to understand, I tried several things that didn't really work for me.

```
IXLCell cell = worksheet.Cell(lineC, colF);
string cellText = cell.GetRichText().ToString();
string[] splitLines = cellText.Split('\n');
```

At this point, my lines are splitted. But I couldn't find any definition that could affect color or font of a single one of these.
So I tried this :

```
var textFirstLine = cellRichText.First();
textFirstLine.Bold = true;
textFirstLine.FontColor = XLColor.FromHtml(myColor);
```

At first I thought that .First() would give me the first line but in fact it is returning the whole cell.
I can't figure it out as far as for now, Any ideas ? is it even possible?

Thanks for your help

Comment: There is some information here https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Using-Rich-Text - maybe extract the contents, split it into lines & then use the example as a way of setting colour/font.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [PaulF](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3070060/paulf) I checked the Github, I feel bad not doing it earlier, but I found a solution :

```
var cellText = worksheet.Cell(lineC, colF);
string[] lines = cellText.Value.ToString().Split('\n');
cellText.GetRichText().Substring(0, lineLength)
    .SetFontColor(XLColor.FromHtml(chain_color))
    .SetBold(TRUE);
```

It didn't work the first time because I used a string var, with which you can't reach the RichText, and in a second time, the def wasn't RichText() but GetRichText()

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
IXLCell cell = worksheet.Cell("A1");

cell.CreateRichText();
cell.GetRichText().AddText("Hello").SetBold(true).SetFontColor(XLColor.PiggyPink);
cell.GetRichText().AddText("World").SetBold(false).SetFontColor(XLColor.Blue);
cell.GetRichText().AddText("Hello!!!!").SetBold(true).SetFontColor(XLColor.Red);
```